# we would otherwise be able to

Tags: meaning

> If God commands or loves what he or she commands or loves because it
> is morally good then this makes morality in some sense independent of
> God. He or she is responding to pre-existing moral values that occur
> in the universe: discovering rather than creating them. On this view,
> it would be possible to describe morality completely without any
> mention of God, though it might be thought that God provides us with
> more reliable information about morality than we would **otherwise**
> be able to glean from the world with our limited intellects.
> Nevertheless, on this view, God is not the source of morality.

Nigel Warburton, Philosophy: The basics

Why did the author put the word "otherwise" there. I think it's redundant. Could you explain it to me?

Answer (score 2):

[**otherwise**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/otherwise) means "in other respects", in this sentence.

So the author is basically saying

> On this view, it would be possible to describe morality completely without any mention of God, though it might be thought that God provides us with more reliable information about morality than we would be able to glean from the world with our limited intellects **in other ways, i.e. if we were not considering God.**

Comment: Or If God didn't provide us with more reliable information about morality?